# Error: cannot use raw constructor reference with explicit type parameters for constructor

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have the following pieces of code:

> Main.java

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     TestProducer c = Test::<String>new;
     System.out.println(c.produce("Point"));
  }
}
```

> Test.java

```
public class Test<N extends CharSequence> {
  private CharSequence name;

  public Test(N k) {
    name = k;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return name.toString();
  }
}
```

> TestProducer.java

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface TestProducer {
  public <N extends CharSequence> Test<N> produce(N str);
}
```

When I compile the code, it produces the following error:

```
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4)
> javac -classpath .:/run_dir/junit-4.12.jar -d . Main.java Test.java TestProducer.java
Main.java:3: error: invalid constructor reference
     TestProducer c = Test::<String>new;
                      ^
  cannot use raw constructor reference with explicit type parameters for constructor
1 error
compiler exit status 1
```

I have the following questions:

1. What is the "raw constructor reference" here ("explicit type parameters" here is `<String>`)?
2. Why can't you "use raw constructor reference with explicit type parameters for constructor" (reasoning/why it's not a good idea)?
3. How can I fix this error (create a TestProducer that only accepts `String`s)?

**EDIT:**

With regards to avoiding the error, here's what I found:
I can modify `TestProducer` to the following:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface TestProducer<N extends CharSequence>
{
  public Test<N> produce(N str);
}
```

and then change `Main.java` like so:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     TestProducer<String> c = Test::new;
     System.out.println(c.produce("Point"));
  }
}
```

By doing this, `c::produce` will only accept `String`s, which fits my intent for question 3. Questions 1 and 2 are still unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You define your `TestProducer` interface not to be generic itself but to have a generic method:

```
Test<N> produce(N str);
```

Then you try to bind a specific type in the assignment:

```
TestProducer c = Test::<String>new;
```

But it's completely valid for me now to say this:

```
c.produce(new StringBuilder())
```

which must return a `Test<StringBuilder>`, not a `Test<String>`.

You should probably add `N` as a type parameter on your interface.

Comment: This answer is useful because the last sentence leads to my approach to part 3. If you can answer the first two parts, I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the type witnesses from around your constructor.  That won't work even in Java *8*.

   ```
   TestProducer c = Test::new;
   System.out.println(c.produce("Point"));
   ```
2. You don't need to provide type witnesses anyway.  `TestProducer` is providing a strongly-enforced contract based on the `produce` method definition, and any producer which doesn't satisfy that definition can't be used.
3. If you wanted a `TestProducer` which ***only*** accepted `String`s, then you'd need to change your bound to `<N extends String>`.